# when I click on the PopupBox this error occurs : Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 51.41842779999999)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, frontend, react-leaflet

> when I click on the PopupBox this error occurs : Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 51.41842779999999)

```
renderMarkerArrays(markers) {
          markers.map(item =>
          item["icon"] =L.icon({
          iconUrl: imgsIcon[item.type] ,
          iconSize: [item.size],
          popupAnchor: [0,50]}))
                   
         return markers.map(element => <Marker  position={element.position} icon={element.icon} onclick{this.handleClick} >
                                         <Popup>
                                          {element.popup}
                                         </Popup>
                                        </Marker>)
```

Comment: So where are you setting the lat and lng values? Seems like you are not getting a number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: after I added element icon I got this problem , when i delete this part no problem occurs